Why scraping function returns null using puppeteer and nextjs
I'm trying web scraping with a simple project that gets a twitter username and displays the related twitter id just like the way the scraped website do it. now everything runs okay (i made sure of scraping by making it headful) but the scraping function returns an empty string.
i have these two files:
"use client"

import { useState } from "react";
import { scrape } from "./search/scrape";

export default function Home() {
  const [searchPrompt, setSearchPrompt] = useState('');
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState('');
  const Submit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const id = await scrape(searchPrompt)
    setUserId(id);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={searchPrompt} onChange={(e) => setSearchPrompt(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={(e) => Submit(e)}>search</button>
      {userId && <div>userid:{userId}</div>}
    </div>
  );
}


"use server"
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

export async function scrape(username) {
    let browser;
    try {
        browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
        const page = await browser.newPage();

        await page.goto('https://ilo.so/twitter-id/');
        await page.setViewport({ width: 1080, height: 1024 });

        await page.type('#id_username', username);

        const parentElement = await page.waitForSelector('#username_form');

        const button = await parentElement.$('button');
        await button.click();

        await page.waitForSelector('#user_id');

        const user_id = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#user_id').textContent);

        return user_id;
    }
    catch (err) {
        return err;
    }
    finally {
        browser.close();
    }

};


somehow the function returns empty string even when i return something like button.textContent EVEN THOUGH the scraping works itself

in the component i tried assigning the returned value to a const then passing it to a setter

also console log doesn't work in the scraping function. neither in the main browser or headful browser

i used this piece when looking for solution too:


await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36'
        });


and this one:

const id =await page.waitForSelector('#user_id');

        const user_id = await id.evaluate((el) => el.textContent);

        return user_id;

yet nothing works.
